# Multiple URLs/Paths for NSDocumentDirectory?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-foundation

Is it possible to get multiple paths or URLs back from either:

```
-[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains]
```

or:

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
```

if the domain is `NSDocumentDirectory`? The API doesn't seem to make any guarantees about how many options will be returned, but almost all uses seem to simply take the resulting `NSArray` and call `firstObject`. That's conceptually simpler than, for instance, iterating across the resulting options, but it makes me wonder if these examples are oversimplified. Would these examples be better off imagining that there may be multiple return values, or would that be over-engineering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've stated, the documentation of the API implies that more than one directory may be returned (even for the documents directory). IIRC as of iOS 9.0 the API will always return a single directory for documents though it's always better to plan ahead and use the API explicitly as intended (simply iterate over all of the results in the order they are received).